# How to change adb shell prompt name before the $ mark?

Tags: android, shell, adb

When I run an Adb command, for example:

```
adb shell
```

It gives me:

```
Android@Glory:/ $
```

What I need is changing the `Android@Glory` to whatever I want, for example to: **Myfirstname**@**Mylastname**

For it to become:

```
Myfirstname@Mylastname:/ $
```

I know it's possible since I saw some devices has people's names written there.

Can anyone tell me what to do? Or try to do? Or what APK I need to modify in order to get it done?

Comment: I think the string that comes after @ is the hostname and the string before that is the user name

Comment: `export HOSTNAME="winterfell"` on my nexus 5 changes it, but it doesn't persist

Comment: It's not helping since it changes the name only temporarily and what I need is changing it permanently

Comment: then you need to root the phone

Answer (score 1):

Open shell.

```
adb shell
```

Get your current prompt to see what it looks like.

```
echo $PS1
```

Change it to whatever you like. For instance, to get a ">", use:

```
PS1=">"
```

Edit: As 3mpty pointed out, you don't necessarily have to change the PS1 variable itself, since it in turn contains other variables that can be changed instead. Exactly which variables it contains, can be displayed by echoing its content as above.

Comment: on Nexus5 Marshmallow build ```PS1``` var uses ```USER``` variable for displaying name before @, so ```export USER="me"``` should change it to me@hostname, or you can use brutal ```export PS1="me@hostname"```

Comment: It's not helping since it changes the name only temporarily and what I need is changing it permanently

Comment: That's how linux shell works, you have to edit some kind of init script to set it when shell is created. You can try with ```/system/etc/mkshrc```.

Comment: I like PS1="`basename $PWD` > "   which prints the current directory and a '>'